# Loading a stream into a Silverlight WebBrowser control

Tags: silverlight, stream, webbrowser-control

Is there a way to load a stream into the Silverlight WebBrowser control?

My use case is that I have HTML files in a XAP that I want to load into the browser without starting a webserver.

Or do I have no option but to start a thin webserver to host the content?

Comment: +1: Really interesting problem. You have the SL to JS bridge so you could in theory send the DOM elements to a browser window, but I must admit I have not tried that with the WebBrowser control (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Its simple enough to load up the `WebBrowser` control with its `NavigateToString` method.

I can't shake the feeling there is more to your question though, you would surely have come across this method when first looking at this problem.

Comment: Hmm... I guess that would work. I am guessing any links/references to images and such will not work since it's not a webserver, but I suppose I'd have the same problem with a stream as well.

Comment: @sohum: Yes it would be a bit of a problem. However consider this:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(VS.85).aspx you could build a system that parsed the HTML (using XML compliant html would help) and replace specially formated src links with a data uri containing a base64 encoded version of a stream for an image that you can take from your Xap.